# Why does applying data validation with Excel Office Script 'break' the excel file?

Tags: excel, office-scripts

I have written an office script that allows a user to add a new entry onto a sheet. They have the ability to ask for a number of rows to be created that relate to that entry. Data validation needs then to be applied to cells within those rows. I am using a list validation and passing the list as a string (side note: according to Microsoft docs you should be able to pass a range, but the script always fails when I do that).

The file saves ok and the data validation works. However, once the file is closed and then reopened, an error occurs. Excel complains that the file is broken and would I like it repaired. Once it has repaired the file, checking the repair log it has removed all of the data validation applied by the office script.

Manually applied data validation does not have the same problem.

Here is my entire script:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    /* Script to add a new project to the Programme
       overview (2) sheet
       */

    const programmeOverview = workbook.getWorksheet('Programme overview (2)');
    const controlSheet = workbook.getWorksheet('Actions');
    const typeColumns = ["E","H","W","Z","AC","AF","AI","AL","AO","AR","AU","AX","BA","BD","BG","BJ","BM","BP","BV","BY","CB",
    "CE","CH","CK","CN","CQ","CT","CW","CZ","DC","DF","DI","DL","DO","DR","DU","DX","EA","ED"];

    // Get the information for the new project
    const projectName = controlSheet.getRange('B2').getValue() as string;
    const dependencies = controlSheet.getRange('B3').getValue() as string;
    const owner = controlSheet.getRange('B4').getValue() as string;

    console.log("Got project information");
    // Get number of resource rows to create
    const numberRows = controlSheet.getRange('B5').getValue() as number;
    
    // Get the last used row in Programme overview (2)
    let usedRowCount = programmeOverview.getUsedRange().getRowCount();

    const firstRow = usedRowCount + 1;
    console.log("Worked out where to stick the project");

    // Unprotect worksheet so we can make changes
    programmeOverview.getProtection().pauseProtection('***************');

    // Add the project name into column A and merge the cells
    let activeCell = programmeOverview.getRange('A' + firstRow);
    activeCell.setValue(projectName);
    let mergeRange = activeCell.getResizedRange(numberRows,0);
    mergeRange.merge();
    mergeRange.getFormat().setVerticalAlignment(ExcelScript.VerticalAlignment.center);
    mergeRange.getFormat().setHorizontalAlignment(ExcelScript.HorizontalAlignment.left);
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeTop).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin); 
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeLeft).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeRight).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeBottom).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);

    // Add dependencies into column B and merge the cells
    activeCell = programmeOverview.getRange('B' + firstRow);
    activeCell.setValue(dependencies);
    mergeRange = activeCell.getResizedRange(numberRows,0);
    mergeRange.merge();
    mergeRange.getFormat().setVerticalAlignment(ExcelScript.VerticalAlignment.center);
    mergeRange.getFormat().setHorizontalAlignment(ExcelScript.HorizontalAlignment.left);
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeTop).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin); 
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeLeft).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeRight).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeBottom).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);

    // Add owner into column C and merge the cells
    activeCell = programmeOverview.getRange('C' + firstRow);
    activeCell.setValue(owner);
    mergeRange = activeCell.getResizedRange(numberRows,0);
    mergeRange.merge();
    mergeRange.getFormat().setVerticalAlignment(ExcelScript.VerticalAlignment.center);
    mergeRange.getFormat().setHorizontalAlignment(ExcelScript.HorizontalAlignment.left);
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeTop).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin); 
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeLeft).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeRight).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);
    mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeBottom).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);

    // Add row headings
    activeCell = programmeOverview.getRange('D' + firstRow);
    activeCell.setValue('Stage');
    activeCell.getFormat().setVerticalAlignment(ExcelScript.VerticalAlignment.center);
    activeCell.getFormat().setHorizontalAlignment(ExcelScript.HorizontalAlignment.left);
    activeCell.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeTop).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin); 
    activeCell.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeLeft).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);
    activeCell.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeRight).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thick);
    activeCell.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeBottom).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);

    activeCell = programmeOverview.getRange('D' + (firstRow + 1));
    activeCell.setValue('Resources');
    if (numberRows - 1 != 0) {
        mergeRange = activeCell.getResizedRange(numberRows - 1,0);
        mergeRange.merge();
        mergeRange.getFormat().setVerticalAlignment(ExcelScript.VerticalAlignment.center);
        mergeRange.getFormat().setHorizontalAlignment(ExcelScript.HorizontalAlignment.left);
        mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeTop).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin); 
        mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeLeft).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);
        mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeRight).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thick);
        mergeRange.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeBottom).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);
    } else {
        activeCell.getFormat().setVerticalAlignment(ExcelScript.VerticalAlignment.center);
        activeCell.getFormat().setHorizontalAlignment(ExcelScript.HorizontalAlignment.left);
        activeCell.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeTop).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin); 
        activeCell.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeLeft).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);
        activeCell.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeRight).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thick);
        activeCell.getFormat().getRangeBorder(ExcelScript.BorderIndex.edgeBottom).setWeight(ExcelScript.BorderWeight.thin);
    }
    console.log("Added project information and formatting");

    // Add stage data validation in
    const stageDataValidation: ExcelScript.DataValidationRule = {
      list: {
        inCellDropDown: true,
        source: "Closure,Configuration,Feasibility,Go/no go,Implementation/Deployement, Migration,On Hold, Pilot,Scoping"
    }};
      
    typeColumns.forEach(col => {
        programmeOverview.getRange(col + firstRow).getDataValidation().setRule(stageDataValidation);
    });

    console.log("Added stage data validation rules");

    // Add resource data validation in

    const resourceDataValidation: ExcelScript.DataValidationRule = {
        list: {
            inCellDropDown: true,
            source: "Clinical Coding, Clinical Safety, Comms and Engagement, Data Analytics, Data Architecture, Data Engineering, Data Quality, Database Administrator (DBA), Desktop Support, Digital Medicines (Pharmacy), Digital Nursing, Information Governance, Programme/Project Management, Service Design, Service Desk, Solutions Development, Systems Support, Technical Operations, Testing, Training, Not Required"
        }
    };

    for (let i = 1; i <= numberRows; i++ ){
        typeColumns.forEach(col => {
            programmeOverview.getRange(col + (firstRow + i)).getDataValidation().setRule(resourceDataValidation);
        });
    }
    console.log("Added resource validation");

    // Add the project separator row
    programmeOverview.getRange("A" + (firstRow+numberRows+1) + ":ED" + (firstRow+numberRows+1)).getFormat().getFill().setColor("#404040");
    programmeOverview.getRange("A" + (firstRow+numberRows+1) + ":ED" + (firstRow+numberRows+1)).getFormat().setRowHeight(14.25);

    // Resume worksheet protection
    programmeOverview.getProtection().protect('************');

    return true
}
```

Anyone else encountering the same or similar problem? Have I made a silly error in my script?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `resumeProtection` instead of `protect()` to resumes worksheet protection. I cannot definitively prove this causes the issue. However, `resumeProtection` is a better approach for resuming protection.

```
    programmeOverview.getProtection().resumeProtection();;
```

btw, I am not sure if the following code works on your side.

```
    // Resume worksheet protection
    programmeOverview.getProtection().protect('************');
```

I think two parameters are must-have for calling `protect()`.

```
  let aSht = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
  let protectionOptions: ExcelScript.WorksheetProtectionOptions = {
    selectionMode: ExcelScript.ProtectionSelectionMode.none
  }
  aSht.getProtection().protect(protectionOptions,'abc');
```

Please ref to

> [ExcelScript.WorksheetProtection interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.worksheetprotection?view=office-scripts#excelscript-excelscript-worksheetprotection-protect-member(1)?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately using resumeProtection hasn't helped. I also tried apply protect with the protection options and this didn't solve the issue either.